# how to get input file name and number of word in each file in map reduce program?

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata

For example there are two text file with words and i need to show below output format how ?please give idea to do ?
1.text1 with words
apple
apple
mango

2.text2 with words
apple
apple
mango

I need to show output like this
text1
apple 2
mango 1

text2
apple 2
mango 1

total
apple 4
mango 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mapper set the key as filename +'|' +word and emit to reducer. In your case the output of the mapper will be like this.

```
(text1|apple,1)
(text1|apple,1)
(text1|mango,1)
(text2|apple,1)
(text2|apple,1)
(text2|mango,1)
```

After the shuffling and sorting phase the output will be like this

```
(text1|apple,{1,1})
(text1|mango,{1})
(text2|apple,{1,1})
(text2|mango,{1})
```

In the reducer you can write the logic to count the number of apples and mangos in each text file.(Count the number of values insist the array)

To find the global sum declare the static variables mangos and apples. Separate the key using the symbol '|' and calculate the sum . Assign the sum to static variables. Finally write the output to the text file